# Add the % on tab when working with HAML on vim

Tags: vim, haml

I'd like to a the ability to type `h3` <kbd>tab</kbd> and have it output `%h3` when working with haml. This would also work with other selectors such as `p` or `section`.

I've installed Tim Pope's [vim-haml](https://github.com/tpope/vim-haml) plugin, but it doesn't seem to provide a shortcut. Have I missed something?

Comment: I don't think this exists yet. Have you consider to write a short script for it?

Comment: Perhaps once I learn more about this. I just switched over to vim and am still getting the hang of things. Maybe this is an opportunity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solution come to my head:

**1)** Hardcode everything using insert mode abbreviations (*aka the easy way*):

```
function! s:haml_settings()
    iabbrev h3      %h3
    iabbrev p       %p
    iabbrev section %section
endfunction

autocmd FileType haml call <sid>haml_settings()
```

Although this way would use `h3<space>` instead of `h3<tab>`.

More information: `:help abbreviations`, especially `:help :iabbrev`

**2)** Remap the tab key (*the more advanced way*):

Remap tab to first execute a certain function, that checks the word under cursor and transforms the text if it found something it can work with, or use the standard behaviour of `<tab>` otherwise.

More information: `:help map-expression`

Comment: This looks very good! I'll have to try this out tomorrow, but I like the idea of using the space instead of the tab since that's my natural inclination. Thnx!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! And just as a little reminder: don't forget to accept the answer that worked for you in the end, even when it takes some days to come around testing it. :)

Comment: Sorry if I stated the obvious. I just looked at the reputation and thought "He must be new to this SO thingy, like me." And that's why assumptions are mostly wrong. :-)

Comment: Alright, @mhinz, I tried the first approach and it didn't take. in my haml file I pressed `h3<space>` and nothing happened

Comment: I might be completely going about this wrong. I'm fairly new to vim.

Comment: Well, the function is only getting called, if the current buffer has the filetype 'haml' set. (Just do `:set ft=haml` and try again.) If your files have a *.haml extension, `autoload BufNewFile,BufRead *.haml call <sid>haml_settings()` might work just as well. (All set in your vimrc, of course.)

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't look this this is working. I added #1 in my vimrc and also `autoload BufNewFile,BufRead *.haml call <sid>haml_settings()` Still nothing. My files have a .haml extension.

Comment: If you open a HAML file, is `:set ft?` (mind the `?` here) showing you `filetype=haml`? Maybe try using both these autocmds: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.haml setlocal filetype=haml` _and_ `autocmd FileType haml call <sid>haml_settings()`. Also, is `:echo has('autocmd')` outputting 1?

Comment: Yep, `:set ft?` shows haml and `:echo has('autocmd') also shows as 1. Here's the weird part. if I type `p <esc>` then it works, except it doesn't add a space at the end so the output is `%p|` (the | is the cursor)

Comment: Hi @mhinz, it seems that this is also being triggered in scss file types. when I run `:set filetype?` it returns `filetype:scss` any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm, maybe because of the vim-haml plugin if you have it still installed? If I put `autocmd FileType haml command Foo echo 'foo'` in my vimrc, `:Foo` is only available in haml files, not scss or sass.

Comment: Yes, vim-haml is still installed, but I need that for syntax coloring, don't I?

Comment: In $VIMRUNTIME/syntax there are files for haml, scss and sass, all of them by tpope. I guess that plugin is just a "github version" of files he submitted to Vim anyway. Thus, highlighting _should_ work without that plugin, because it seems to get shipped by default.

Comment: so weird. I commented out the command in my vimrc, restarted vim, then uncommented and restarted vim and it's back to being option+space to do the task. Not really sure what's happening. This solution is buggy, but it works for now. I have having to type % before a tag. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more powerful alternative to abbreviations is to use a snippet-expansion plugin. [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) being the most obvious choices but there are others.

The two plugins above can use [the same snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets). There are already [some](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/haml.snippets) for `haml` and it's extremely easy to add yours.

Comment: I mostly thought about how I would implement such a behaviour, but snippet plugins are always a good alternative in such cases. :) As always, it all boils down to familarity with Vim, time available to put into the task, "is there a plugin out there already doing this exact/similar thing?", personal taste, mood, time of the day, and the state of Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: @mhinz, `iabbrev` is what I though about first but you cowardly took advantage of my daily commute to post your answer so I went with plan B.

Comment: Haha, from now on I'll try to pay more attention to your daily commute times. ;-) Probably using a script that blocks SO via /etc/hosts for certain time ranges!