# Adding the % to a tag automatically in haml and only in haml

Tags: vim, haml

I asked about this previously here: [Add the % on tab when working with HAML on vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264368/add-the-on-tab-when-working-with-haml-on-vim)

The solution there was okay, but it turns out that the function call is also being triggered in scss file types.

Here's what I currently have:

```
function! s:haml_settings()
  iabbrev h1        %h1
  iabbrev p         %p
  iabbrev section   %section
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.haml setlocal filetype=haml
autocmd FileType haml call <sid>haml_settings()
```

I'm pretty new to vim so please forgive me if I'm asking a noobie question.

How do I make sure this function is only called in HAML files? Or if that can't be accomplished, how can I remap it so it only fires when I press `option-space` before a given tag? I'm on a mac so I have an option key.

In other words: I'd like it if I could press `p<space>` then have the output be `%p` (with the space after it). Or I'd like to press `p<option><space>` and have it output the same `%p`)

I have tim popes vim-haml plugin, but it doesn't provide this kind of functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make your abbreviations local to the buffer:

```
iabbrev <buffer> h1 %h1
```

Or try a snippet engine like snipmate or utisnips.

Comment: It appears this no longer works after updating to vim 7.4.22. I have no idea why?

Comment: So, this stopped working after I upgraded to 7.4. I haven't been able to figure out what happened. Any pointers? I would really appreciate any help. Thnx!

Comment: @DavidBecerra, like I already told you before, it works perfectly fine here and at work. Abbreviations are not supposed to be broken in 7.4 so the problem is elsewhere. If you want help on that specific issue, ask another question and provide as much detail about your configuration as possible.

Comment: You're right! Again sorry, I'm very new to vim and am still trying to wrap my head around it all... If anyone is having issues with this take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20587336/826530

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, but I'll share with others in case they also run into this.

It appears the [Auto Pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) plugin had been the culprit. Once I disabled this plugin, the space bar worked fine with abbreviations.

I discovered this by `:verbose imap <space>`, which pointed me directly to the source of the problem.

Comment: My specific issue as to why it wasn't working before.